# SQL query - table cloning

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, I don't know if they all need to be used, but basically I need Table A and Table C to be compared, if there is an ID that is in Table A that is not in Table C, then in Table C the ID is to be added along with value in another cell in that row. See below for an example:

Original Table A:

```
-------------------------
Sku | Status
-------------------------
ABC | Enabled
DEF | Enabled
GHI | Enabled
JKL | Disabled
MNO | Enabled
```

Original Table C:

```
-------------------------
Sku | Status
-------------------------
ABC | Enabled
DEF | Enabled
GHI | Enabled
```

After Query Table C:

```
-------------------------
Sku | Status
-------------------------
ABC | Enabled
DEF | Enabled
GHI | Enabled
JKL | Disabled
MNO | Disabled
```

Comment: What if table C contains a record but with another value? (ABC, Disabled), for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO b 
SELECT * 
FROM a 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT * FROM b WHERE b.sku = a.sku);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!!
Try with something similar to:

```
INSERT INTO TableC (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE TableA.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM TableC) )
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if mysql supports this syntax, but this should also work:

```
insert into c (sku, status)
(select sku, status from a where not exists (select null from c where c.sku = a.sku))
;
```